# Font Awesome does not work in Firefox when optimized and CDN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using [Font Awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) in my ASP.NET MVC 4 project as a [`UseCdn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundlecollection.usecdn.aspx) bundle:

```
bundles.UseCdn = true;
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fontawesome/css")
                   .Include("~/Content/css/font-awesome.css‌​‌​"));
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```

However when I turn on UseCdn and [EnableOptimizations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundletable.enableoptimizations.aspx) the CSS file does not render in Firefox. It does work in Chrome.

What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i am using font awesome in website project, using asp.net MVC4, after bundle the css file, font awesome supported in chrome, but not in firefox browser. why does not supported in firefox browser?

Comment: bundles.UseCdn = true; bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/fontawesome/css").Include("~/Content/css/font-awesome.css‌​")); BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true; sir, here i am using CDN also, when i use this CDN and Bundlesoptimization in asp.net mvc4, when i enable bundle optimization is true, the css file does nor rendering in firefox..

Answer (score 1):

Are you behind a proxy? If you are, you may be running into a security issue in that Firefox will not download a custom font if you are sitting behind a proxy. Bring up Firebug, and then browse your page and see if you get any errors relating to your font not being delivered through your proxy as it is a cross-domain request.

FYI:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=627616

Comment: Interesting, but that's quite an old bug. Is that likely to still be a problem?

Comment: Yep, the behaviour persists as it's not a bug, it's a feature! I recently worked at a newspaper where our software demanded we run Firefox, but we could never see our custom font until we published outside the intranet or brought our page up in another browser.